# What is the range of information gain ratio?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, data-mining, information-theory, mutual-information

I am wondering what the value range of [information gain ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio) is. I guess it is [0,1] but am not too sure about it.

Comment: Why would you say [0,1]?  If the numerator is greater than the denominator it would be greater than 1.

Comment: Exactly - but can the numerator be greater? This is the question.

Comment: This site repeats my assumption as a fact: http://pythonhosted.org/ibmdbpy/feature_selection.html

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr**
Intuitively, the information gain ratio is the ratio between the mutual information of two random variables and the entropy of one of them. Thus, it is guaranteed to be in $[0,1]$ (except for the case in which it is undefined).

In the context of decision trees, let's denote:

- $Ex$ is the set of training examples
- $X$ is a randomly chosen example in $Ex$
- $a$ is some feature
- $A$ is the value of $a$ of $X$
- $C$ is the class of $X$
- $IG(Ex,a)$ is the information gain for splitting according to $a$
- $IV(Ex,a)$ is the information value (aka intrinsic value) of $a$
- $IGR(Ex,a)$ is the information gain ratio for splitting according to $a$
- $H(Y)$ is the entropy of $Y$ (for any random variable $Y$)
- $I(Y;Z)$ is the mutual information of $Y$ and $Z$ (for any two random variables $Y,Z$)

Then, by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio):

$IG(Ex,a)=H(C)-H(C|A)$

$IV(Ex,a)=H(A)$

$IGR(Ex,a)=\frac{IG(Ex,a)}{IV(Ex,a)}$

Thus:

$IGR(Ex,a)=\frac{H(C)-H(C|A)}{H(A)}$

First, if $H(A)=0$, then $IGR(Ex,a)$ is undefined. An example for such case is when $A$ is constant.

Now, let's assume that $H(A) \ne 0$.

As wikipedia [mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Relation_to_conditional_and_joint_entropy):

$I(C;A)=H(C)-H(C|A)$ and $I(A;C)=H(A)-H(A|C)$.

From the [definition of mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Definition), we can deduce that it's symmetric.

Thus, $H(C)-H(C|A)=I(C;A)=I(A;C)=H(A)-H(A|C)$

Therefore:

$IGR(Ex,a)=\frac{H(A)-H(A|C)}{H(A)}=1-\frac{H(A|C)}{H(A)}\le 1$ 
(The $\le 1$ is given by the [non-negativity of entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Further_properties).)

We can also show that $IGR(Ex,a) \ge 0$, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51702020/5728089), and so it holds that $0 \le IGR(Ex,a) \le 1$.